# How to export pandas DataFrame to excel without deleting other sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, finance

For my code I import the data from a sheet called in put so the code reads

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('Portfolio.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Input')
```

then I do all my analytics and export the result like this

```
df2.to_excel('Portfolio.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Output')
```

When I open the excel sheet the it deletes the input sheet and just has the Outputed data.
Is there a way to export the data without deleting the other sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an *ExcelWriter* object (as stated in the docs: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html][1])

```
  with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

Comment: This does not prevent other sheets from being deleted